# Refreshing PivotTable in Excel 2007 VBA doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to update a pivot table from VBA after it's source sql data table is refreshed. No matter what I do, the Pivot Table will only get refreshed the **2nd time** this code is executed. I've tried all combinations and orders of pivot.RefreshTable and pivot.Update, adding Do Events, setting Application.ScreenUpdating to false before and True after. I'm running out of ideas. Each Time the data is modified in SQL,  I have to execute it once to see it in the source table and again to see it in the pivot table.

```
Dim c As WorkbookConnection
Set c = ThisWorkbook.Connections.Item("Sheet1")

sSQL = "Select * from Table1 "     

c.OLEDBConnection.CommandText = sSQL
c.OLEDBConnection.CommandType = xlCmdSql
c.Refresh

For Each pivot In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables

    pivot.RefreshTable
    pivot.Update
    pivot.PivotCache.Refresh
    DoEvents
    pivot.RefreshTable
    pivot.Update
    pivot.PivotCache.Refresh
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried going through with break points to see if it does get updated at all on first attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the connection doesn't refresh in the background:

```
Dim c As WorkbookConnection
Set c = ThisWorkbook.Connections.Item("Sheet1")

sSQL = "Select * from Table1 "     

c.OLEDBConnection.CommandText = sSQL
c.OLEDBConnection.CommandType = xlCmdSql
c.OLEDBConnection.Backgroundquery = False
c.Refresh

For Each pivot In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables

    pivot.RefreshTable

Next
```